# Parallax effect supposedly applied to <section> is applied to every background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just followed this tutorial on creating simple parallax effects with jQuery: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641

My only issue is that when I write my slightly altered version of his jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('section').each(function(){
      console.log($(this));
      var $bgobj = $(this); // assigning the objecti
      $(window).scroll(function(){
       var yPos = -($(window).scrollTop / $bgobj.data('speed'));
       var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
       $bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
      });
    });
  });
```

Instead of each `<section>` having the backgroundPosition changed, all of my elements with a background image (including ones outside of a `<section>` tag) have the effect applied.

When I do `console.log()` to see what elements are getting selected I get the following:

```
jQuery.fn.init[1]
```

exactly two times which is how many `<section>` tags I have in the DOM. However, what is weird is that there is a third element which is having the parallax effect applied to its `background` image.

Here is my html:

```
#welcome.container
  .row
    %section#home.pages{"data-speed" => "10", "data-type" => "background"}
      .col-md-4
      .col-md-8
        %article
          %h2#fls-title
            Study English at FLS International
            %br
              English Language Schools
          %p#fls-text
            It’s easy to learn English as a Second Language (ESL) with FLS International intensive English courses. The ESL schools of FLS International use a modern curriculum that exemplifies how to learn English language skills most effectively—by combining English speaking, listening and reading in a supportive learning environment.
            %form{:action => "#{url_for(:controller =>'school_applications', :action =>'new')}"}
              %input{:type => "submit", :value => "Apply Now"}/

  %p
  %p
  %br/
  .row
    .col-md-4
      #red.quote
        I will never forget the time I spent here.
        .signature Jeremy, Switzerland
    .col-md-4
      #blue.quote
        Since I entered FLS, I have never regretted my decision because the classes offered by FLS are all fantastic.
        .signature Chia-Yuan, Taiwan
    .col-md-4
      #gold.quote
        The quality of teachers is good.
        .signature Masaru, Japan
  .row
    %section#some
      .col-md-2
      .col-md-10
        %article
          %h2#nine-levels
            Nine Levels of ESL Courses Mean Everyone
            %br
              Can Learn the English Language
          %p#nine-levels-text
            FLS International offers core programs that put learning the English language within the reach of all students. We cover nine levels of English, from English for beginners to an advanced English course that prepares students for entrance into American colleges and universities. All students who study English at FLS participate in the core program and can take additional elective classes that target specific areas for improvement. In addition, all FLS students benefit from such specialized learning aids as English Everywhere and Language Extension Days.
  %p
  %p
  %br/ 
.h2
  #gram_headings
    \#myflsadventure
#myflsadventure
.h2
  #gram_headings
    \#flssummer2014
#flssummer2014
#welcome.container
  .row
  .row
    .col-md-4
    %div{class: "col-md-4\""}
      %video{controls: "", height: "240", width: "320"}
        %source{src: "#{asset_path('title00.mp4')}", type: "video/mp4"}
```

The `.row` with all of the `#color-name.quote` tags is having the parallax effect applied to it when it shouldn't.

Here is the Css bits with the background images:

```
#blue{
 background: url(image_path("web_circ_blue.png")) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; min-height: 1000px; 
}
#gold{
 background: url(image_path("web_circ_gold.png")) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; min-height: 1000px;
}
#red{
 background: url(image_path("web_circ_red.png")) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; min-height: 1000px; 
}
 #home {
  margin-right:200px;
  background: url(image_path("1IMG_1338.JPG")) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; min-height: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#some {
  margin-right:200px;
  background: url(image_path("1IMG_1341.JPG")) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed; min-height: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

Here is the sample of the phenomenon. Notice during the row of quotes the blue circle is parallaxed in the background between the two intentionally parallaxed `<section>` s

https://fls-net.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Can you please show us an example (site or http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @dwhite.me I have added the link.